# How to upload file along with data from Angular to .NET core

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, .net-core

I have running Angular 9 application and I wanted to implement File upload behavior. In the form, user has to enter title, description and **upload only one file in .zip format** and while clicking on Submit, I want to send the form values along with files to Backend (using dotnet) via http post call.

**file-upload.component.ts**

```
        uploadFile(files) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            const fileToUpload = files[0] as File;
            formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
            const data = {
               title: this.form.value.Title,
               description: this.form.value.Description,
               File: formData
            };
            console.log(data);
            this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/idea/add', data).subscribe((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }});
        }
```

**file-upload.component.html**

```
<input type="file" #file placeholder="Choose file" (change)="uploadFile(file.files)" multiple>
```

**FileController.cs**

```
[HttpPost("api/idea/add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddIdea([FromBody] IdeaDto ideaDto) { }
```

Backend expects the data to come in below format

**IdeaDto.cs**

```
public class IdeaDto
{
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting below error while submitting the data

[image]

Also, I did console.log(data) and got File value as shown in the below image. I am not sure whether this the correct data

[image]

What is wrong here? I'm really out of ideas, maybe I need a fresh thoughts on this after spending so much time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take from form in api

```
[HttpPost("api/idea/add")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddIdea([FromForm] IdeaDto ideaDto) { }
```

and in angular fill formdata rather than create object

```
uploadFile(files) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            const fileToUpload = files[0] as File;
            formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
            formData.append('title',this.form.value.Title);
            formData.append('description',this.form.value.Description);
            console.log(data);
            this.http.post('https://localhost:5001/api/idea/add', formData ).subscribe((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }});
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you post binary data like files, they have to be posted as multi-part form data, please use the below header

`Content-Type: multipart/form-data;`

In the model, you should receive the data as File instead of a custom interface (`IFormFile`)